# How do I filter an XML file to find all of one type of tag with any invalid values?

Tags: windows, notepad++, grep, find, xml

I was messing around with notepad++, but seem to find an easy way to do this.  I think grep might work, but I an not totally sure how.

I have a file, that has certain tags, I want to find all of the tags, that have incorrect values. For example:

This is what most of them are.

```
<tag attr="1">Correct</tag>
```

However, I want to find all the ones with anything else in them.

```
<tag attr="1">Wrong</tag>
<tag attr="1">Incorrect</tag>
<tag attr="1">Gibberish</tag>
```

... etc, etc ...

There are thousands of them, but I am just looking for bad ones.  I don't want to look at each manually.  Also, more than on tag can be on the same line.

GC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use a XML parser, but, if you want to use Notepad++, this does the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `<tag[^>]*>(?:(?!Correct|</tag>).)*</tag>`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<tag[^>]*>          # open tag
            # Tempered Greedy Token
(?:                 # non capture group
    (?!                 # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after:
        Correct             # literally Correct
      |                   # OR
        </tag>              # end tag
    )                   # end lookahead
    .                   # any character
)*                  # end group, may appear 0 or more times
</tag>              # end tag
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use CTRL H (find/replace) with REGEX turned on. Dots are a single wildcard, .* is everything. If you want to work with line breaks, \r\n or \n will be your friend too. What defines a correct tag's contents? Is it always one word, or length?

For example, ....g is regex for literally any tag attr 1 with a contents of 4 charachters and a g.

Second, \r\n....g  is a regex for the same, but there is a new line after the opening tag and before the contents of the tag. Some more details would help zero in on the exact regex for n++ So send more details if needed.

you can also do ()(....g)() to parse out the three sections. $1 etc is how to address the parsed parts. $1$2$3 is literal pasteback.

Answer (score 0):

Find an XML editor that allows XPath searching (I use oXygen), and the query is then `//tag[not(.='Correct')]`.

If you're doing anything with XML, you need to master XPath: working with regular expressions to process XML is inefficient, clumsy, and ultimately it gives the wrong answer - there will always be some way of writing the XML that defeats your regex. For example people doing this with a regex often forget that attributes can be delimited by single quotes rather than double quotes, or that a newline can appear before the ">" in a start tag.